# Remove trailing whitespace recursively only at end of file using grep/sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Basically, I've got about 1,500 files and the last character of any of these files should not be any type of white space.

How do I check a bunch of files to make sure that they don't end in some form of whitespace?(newline, space, carriage return, tab, etc.)?

Comment: Text files should end with a newline; to do otherwise can lead to undefined behaviour with the I/O system.  Unix really doesn't care (though some programs do).  Other systems may not be as tolerant.  And 'sed' and 'awk' will add a newline, at least unless you work quite hard.  You'd have to drop into Perl or Python or ... to get no newline at the end.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Well, the problem is they are PHP files and an XML feed is generated from them.  If they contain whitespace in the wrong places, XML pukes all over the place.

Comment: Really?  That sounds like a problem with the XML more than anything.  And I still think you will want a newline at the end of the last line for sanity's sake.  No more than one newline - that I have no problem with.  But the question asks for a much more stringent condition than that.  I'm all in favour of no trailing blanks or tabs (ask my team!), and no redundant blank lines (more than 2 blank lines is very, very seldom warranted in my book; I usually strip to just one blank line at a time unless the code is really consistently formatted with double blank lines (but it never is!).

Comment: @Jonathan: The rules for when whitespace is considered "significant" in XML are gross, and depend on whether the containing element is declared in the DTD as having "mixed" content or not: http://www.usingxml.com/Basics/XmlSpace  Ran into issues myself when trying to transform XML with XSLT.

Comment: This is a hole in my linux knowledge, so take this with a gain of salt.  Can't you just open the file in a memory mapped way and move backwards from the end and shrinking the file by one for any  combination of \s \r \n that occurs at the very end?  Never tried mem mapped files in linux, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{if (flag) print line; line = $0; flag = 1} END {gsub("[[:space:]]+$","",line); printf line}'
```

**Edit:**

New version:

The `sed` command removes all the trailing lines that consist of only whitespace then the `awk` command removes the ending newline.

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/{:a;$d;N;/\n[[:space:]]*$/ba}' inputfile |
    awk '{if (flag) print line; line = $0; flag = 1} END {printf line}'
```

The disadvantage is that it reads the file twice.

**Edit 2:**

Here's an all-awk solution that only reads the file once. It accumulates white-space-only lines in a manner similar to the `sed` command above.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# accumulate a run of white-space-only lines so they can be printed or discarded
/^[[:space:]]*$/ {
    accumlines = accumlines nl $0
    nl = "\n"
    accum = 1
    next
}

# print the previous line and any accumulated lines, store the current line for the next pass
{
    if (flag) print line
    if (accum) { print accumlines; accum = 0 }
    accumlines = nl = ""
    line = $0
    flag = 1
}

# print the last line without a trailing newline after removing all trailing whitespace
# the resulting output could be null (nothing rather than 0x00)
# note that we're not print the accumulated lines since they're part of the 
# trailing white-space we're trying to get rid of
END {
    gsub("[[:space:]]+$","",line)
    printf line
}
```

**Edit 3:**

- removed unnecessary `BEGIN` clause
- changed `lines` to `accumlines` so it's easier to distinguish from `line` (singular)
- added comments

Comment: Will this remove multiple whitespace-containing lines at the end of the file, or only the last such line?

Comment: Not very familiar with awk but I think this does handle the multiple-trailing-blank-lines case incorrectly.  -1 for now.

Comment: OK that last solution is correct I believe, -1 reverted.  Can't quite bring myself to +1 it though...

Comment: The use of END block at the awk script is not quite correct . Since the last non-whitespace line of the file is printed at this block, ENDFILE should be used instead of END. END block executes only once at the end of the script, but last non-whitespace line should be output after finishing processing each file. This version would work identical in most cases, however will fail when inplace mode is used or multiple files are processed with this awk script.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor: At the time that I wrote this answer, I don't believe gawk 4, which added `ENDFILE`, had been released yet. Also note that my script should run OK (except for in the circumstances you describe) in non-gawk versions of AWK which don't have `ENDFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

This will strip all trailing whitespace:

```
perl -e '$s = ""; while (defined($_ = getc)) { if (/\s/) { $s .= $_; } else { print $s, $_; $s = ""; } }' < infile > outfile
```

There's probably an equivalent in `sed` but I'm much more familiar with Perl, hope that works for you.  Basic idea: if the next character is whitespace, save it; otherwise, print any saved characters followed by the character just read.  If we hit EOF after reading one or more whitespace characters, they won't be printed.

This will simply detect trailing whitespace, giving an exit code of 1 if so:

```
perl -e 'while (defined($_ = getc)) { $last = $_; } exit($last =~ /\s/);' < infile > outfile
```

**[EDIT]**
The above describes how to detect or change a single file.  If you have a large directory tree containing files that you want to apply the changes to, you can put the command in a separate script:

### fix.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$s = "";
while (defined($_ = getc)) {
    if (/\s/) { $s .= $_; } else { print $s, $_; $s = ""; }
}
```

and use it in conjunction with the `find` command:

```
find /top/dir -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "{}.bak" && fix.pl < "{}.bak" > "{}"' ';'
```

This will move each original file to a backup file ending in ".bak".  (It would be a good idea to test this on a small test fileset first.)

Comment: So this reads character-by-character instead of line-by-line? By the way, I don't think there's any way `sed` can do it.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes.  All reads will be buffered by the OS so it won't be terribly slow.  (Although it seems likely that the file consists of short, text lines in this case, reading a line at a time risks bad performance and high memory usage on files with very long lines or binary files that may contain few `\n` characters.)

Comment: There probably isn't an equivalent in `sed`; it deals in lines and therefore emits a newline.

Comment: Uh oh, I fear I didn't explain my problem accurately enough....those 1,500 files that I have are in directories and subdirectories, can your code be used to start in a given directory and scan each subdir?

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Ok, I'll use find.  Care to enlighten me a bit further on how to use find to replace all blank lines/whitespaces at EOF recursively?

Comment: @MALON: Added a bit more info in the main answer, let me know if anything's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier reading the file from the bottom to the top:

```
tac filename | 
awk '
    /^[[:space:]]*$/ && !seen {next} 
    /[^[:space:]]/   && !seen {gsub(/[[:space:]]+$/,""); seen=1}
    seen
' | 
tac
```

Comment: Creative :)  But the line #4 starts `/[^[:` when it should be `/^[[:`, and I believe the 1st argument to `gsub` should be `/^[[:space:]]+/`.  Can't +1 as this will be pretty inefficient -- the 2nd `tac` takes its input from a pipe and so has to wait for the entire result of `awk` to be saved before it can start.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: No, the caret indicates "not" in that line. In the line before it, it indicates "beginning of line". The `gsub` is looking at whitespace at the end of the line rather than lines that consist only of whitespace. There **is a problem, however.** The script uses AWK's default output, `print`, so a newline is appended. Also, the file contents are processed *three* times.

Comment: @Dennis: I see now that `/[^[:` is (surprisingly enough!) the right thing, thanks, but I think you're wrong about the `gsub` part -- remember, we're still dealing with *reversed* input at this point, so we should be stripping whitespace from the *beginning* of the line.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: `tac` reverses top to bottom, `rev` reverses left to right. So `$` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a plain C answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c, bufsize = 100, ns = 0;
    char *buf = malloc(bufsize);

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (ns == bufsize) buf = realloc(buf, bufsize *= 2);
            buf[ns++] = c;
        } else {
            fwrite(buf, 1, ns, stdout);
            ns = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Not much longer than [Dennis's awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727268/remove-trailing-whitespace-recursively-only-at-end-of-file-using-grep-sed/4727389#4727389), and, dare I say, it, easier to understand!  :-P

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
# command-line arguments are the names of the files to check.
# output is names of files that end with trailing whitespace
for (@ARGV) {
  open F, '<', $_;
  seek F, -1, 2;                # seek to before last char in file
  print "$_\n" if <F> =~ /\s/
}
```

Comment: so what about the rest of the lines, if i interpret your code correctly.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted the question as only worrying about the end of the file, not the end of each line.

Comment: @ghostdog74: mob's interpretation is correct -- check the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -e 's=ARGF.read;s.rstrip!;print s' file
```

basically, read the whole file, strip the last whitespace if any, and print out the contents. So this solution is not for VERY huge files.

Comment: Am I right in thinking this reads the whole file into memory?

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `man ed` to delete trailing white space at file end and `man dd` to delete a final newline (although keep in mind that ed reads the whole file into memory and performs an in-place edit without any kind of previous backup):

```
# tested on Mac OS X using Bash
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
   # remove white space at end of (non-empty) file
   # note: ed will append final newline if missing
   printf '%s\n' H '$g/[[:space:]]\{1,\}$/s///g' wq | ed -s "${file}"
   printf "" | dd  of="${file}" seek=$(($(stat -f "%z" "${file}") - 1)) bs=1 count=1
   #printf "" | dd  of="${file}" seek=$(($(wc -c < "${file}") - 1)) bs=1 count=1
done < <(find -x "/path/to/dir" -type f -not -empty -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 2. Linux syntax. Proper command.

```
find /directory/you/want -type f | \ 
xargs --verbose -L 1 sed -n --in-place -r \
':loop;/[^[:space:]\t]/ {p;b;}; N;b loop;'
```

Version 1. Remove whitespace at the end of each line. FreeBSD syntax.

```
find /directory/that/holds/your/files -type f | xargs -L 1  sed  -i '' -E 's/[:         :]+$//'
```

where the white space in `[:         :]` actually consists of one space and one tab characters.
With space it's easy. You just hit the space button. In order to get tab character inserted press Ctrl-V and then Tab in the shell.

Comment: This only trims whitespace from the end of each line -- the asker wants to trim all whitespace characters from the end of the *file* (which may span 1 or more lines).

Comment: Also `sed` takes a `-e` option, not `-E`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: OS X (and BSD) `sed` accepts `-E` for extended regular expressions (GNU `sed` uses `-r`).

Comment: Indeed. I didn't notice about the end of the file. I'll try to rewrite tomorrow.

Comment: @akond: Encouraging to see `sed` nearly getting there, -1 reverted.  But: I think your new regex should be either `/[^ <->\n]/` (with `<->` = Tab) or `/[^[:space:]]/`.  The `\t` and colons shouldn't be there.  Also there seems to be a final `\n` still left at the end of the output file -- is it possible to get rid of this with `sed`?

Comment: FreeBSD's sed does not support \t. Also [:space:] does not include \t for one reason or another. So I switched to this alternative syntax. Concerning a final \n, I was on the fence whether to leave it or remove it, and thought it would be nice to have it, since it's Unix way of having text files. But if you insist, I could reconsider.

Comment: @akond: That character class should include *either* a literal tab character or `\t`, but not both.  Preferably the former since that will then work on BSD -- your current pattern will match literal backslashes and "t"s on BSD which is incorrect.  And the colons match literal colons, causing actual colons at the end of file to be deleted which is incorrect obviously (try it).  Concerning the final `\n`, I'd suggest getting rid of it as the OP wants, optionally giving code that leaves it on (but give that code second).

Answer (score 0):

Using `man dd` without `man ed`:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
   filesize="$(wc -c < "${file}")"
   while [[ $(tail -c 1 "${file}" | tr -dc '[[:space:]]' | wc -c) -eq 1 ]]; do
      printf "" | dd  of="${file}" seek=$(($filesize - 1)) bs=1 count=1
      let filesize-=1
   done
done < <(find -x "/path/to/dir" -type f -not -empty -print0)
```